# Solve for exponent in modular exponentiation

Tags: modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

If given that

```
N^x mod C = B
```

How does one solve for x if (x > 1).
I did CRT and got 1, so does anyone know what direction I should go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is known as the discrete logarithm problem. This isn't an easy problem in the general case, no $P$ algorithm is known to exist.

However, there exists algorithms that solve it in $O(n^{\log n})$ in finite fields : http://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.4244.pdf.

Some instances of the problem may be solved by hand, or quicker.

Furthermore, there exist algorithms better than the brute-force. Using a baby-step-giant-step method speeds up the search a lot.

Comment: Thank you, if there was a co-prime relationship would it be possible?

Comment: I have edited my post. If you need to solve a specific instance of the problem, maybe you should post it.

Comment: I do, but your answer gave me the right things to google. thank you!

Comment: You're welcome !